# Generate selenium query dynamically using a string in Java

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic, find, element

I was trying to generate a selenium query dynamically as follows but it did not work:

```
String Query = "By."+Selector+"("+Expression+")))";

element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(Query));
```

How to achieve this requirement please?

Comment: What do you mean it did not work? Did it throw an exception? Did you get the wrong values? Did you nuke a neighbouring country :) ? Please also provide values for `Selector` and `Expression`.

Comment: :) I'm getting : `The method elementToBeClickable(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (String)` even after assigning values to variables.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) and the error you are getting, there does not seem to exist an `elementToBeClickable` method which takes a string as parameter.

Checking the [`By`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) documentation however, which seems to be one of the input parameters which the method you are after takes, one can see that they can construct it from a string.

In short, your code would need to change to something like so:

```
String cssQuery = ... //You can construct the CSS query dynamically.
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(cssQuery)));
```

Comment: Make sense. So I am restricted to use a string argument only inside the By.cssSelector() and not inside elementToBeClickable(). Ok, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to get an element By query, using **selector** and **expression** parameters and then pass result to ExpectedConditions.
So may be you need universal method for this?

Like:

```
public By getSeleniumQuery(String selector, String expression){
    if(selector.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
        return By.id(expression);
    }
    else if(selector.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
        return By.name(expression);
    }
    else if(selector.equalsIgnoreCase("class")){
        return By.className(expression);
    }
    else if(selector.equalsIgnoreCase("css")){
        return By.cssSelector(expression);
    }
    else if(selector.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
        return By.linkText(expression);
    }
    else if(selector.equalsIgnoreCase("partialLink")){
        return By.partialLinkText(expression);
    }
    else if(selector.equalsIgnoreCase("tag")){
        return By.tagName(expression);
    }
    else if(selector.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")){
        return By.xpath(expression);
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown selector - " + selector);
    }
}
```